# Getting ANR when using the C2DM push service

Tags: android, timeout

I'm currently developing an android app using the C2DM push service. Of course it runs smootly in the emulator, but when I installed on my device, I'm getting application timeouts because of the internet speed conection or so.

What can i do to prevent this?

Comment: Do you mean delay between sending push from server and obtaining broadcast on device?

Answer (score 0):

There is not much to do. When sending the C2DM message you can specify the importance of the message (should it wake the device, or wait for when the user wakes it). However, this will only happen, if you specify it with the field `delay_while_idle`.

Two factors come in to play: Is the phone connected to Google (is the connection green in the top bar (on nexus one at least)) and how fast is the connection. The only way you can speed this up, is to be on wifi, as far as I know.